# How to get part of file from Google Drive via direct link

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive for my files. Those files are in custom format (like a container with metadata+data).

Can I get direct link to part of file? I mean, can I specify offset and length of file slice inside URL query string (nor XmlHTTPRequest params, nor HTTP heades) to use it for example in *src* attribute in html *img* element and get only part of file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using simple proxy.

Proxy just parse offset and length params from GET query string and create request to Google Drive with these values into HTTP Range headers.
And then just redirect response from Google Drive back to the client.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible at the moment. Partial uploads and downloads are what we consider in our future plans. Maybe your use case would fit it there.